# Is there a way to hijack what is in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface

When I console.log a value, I get immediate response. But, the html takes time. 
I know what the issue is and it has nothing to do with async or anything.

Is there a way to get what you are console.logging without doing a return?
Possibly saving it in localStorage.

"status" comes from third party API where it's boolean.The value changes from true to false based on user input. Which is correct. But, HTML takes time for it to change in timely manner

```
public elementEvent($event) {
    this.isValid = $event.status;
    console.log($event.status);
}

//output: true
```

```
<div>{{isValid}}</div>

//output: false
```

Comment: What is it you need to do?  I don't quite understand what you're trying to do here. "But, the HTML takes time" -- do you mean rendering the page?  Would you like to log the output of a running function? Not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: Basically, the DOM gets the data and changes in timely manner, but HTML updates takes time.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "html updates takes time"?? This is a vague question and will likely be close voted without additional details. Including an [mcve] which might illustrate the problem would be helpful as well.

Comment: I have made change to my question. I now hope you understand what I am asking

Comment: As Igor alludes to, having a reproducible example of your problem is what will help us understand the issue you're having.

Comment: Do you mean maybe that change detection does not occur as fast as you think it should? I would urge you to create an [mcve] (focus on the *reproducible*). The goal being that anyone can take the code, run it, and experience the same thing you are.

Comment: Well not as fast as the DOM. I cannot set an example because I am using a 3rd party API, where it cannot be used without token

Comment: This sounds more of an event loop delaying the task to paint html vs logging data in the console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497082/html-doesnt-read-change-value-angular-4 Why you asked this twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML doesn't read change value (Angular 4+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497082/html-doesnt-read-change-value-angular-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I had to do:

```
public elementEvent($event) {
    this.isValid = $event.status;
    this.ref.detectChanges();

}
```